# div tags are selectable in iOS app built with PhoneGap

Tags: html, ios, cordova

I am building an app using PhoneGap and I've noticed that div tags are selectable as following[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file

```
body
      {
         -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
         -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome all / Safari all */
         -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox all */
         -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
           user-select: none;/* Likely future */
      }
```

Comment: Can you explain what each field means?

Comment: The -webkit-touch-callout CSS property disables the default callout shown when you touch and hold a touch target.

When a target is touched and held on iPhone OS, Safari displays a callout information about the link. This property allows disabling that behavior.


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select